# How to reuse Kotlin coroutine after error handling?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How reuse the coroutine after error handling?
In my code I recreate a new job and scope instance when any error on coroutine (using CoroutineExceptionHandler), It work's, buy I think that it is not a good chooise, maybe have another alternative

```
    fun getDashBoardData() {
            loadingStateLiveData.value = true
            scope.launch(scope.coroutineContext + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
                assetsBalanceLiveData.postValue(Resource.error(app.getString(R.string.no_connection), null))
                Log.e(TAG, "CoroutineExceptionHandler - ${e.message}")
                job = Job()
                scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)
                loadingStateLiveData.postValue(false)
            }) {
              // SUSPENDED FUN   
              assetsBalanceLiveData.postValue(DashboardRepository.getUserAssetsBalance())

              // SUSPENDED FUN    
              incomeGraphDataLiveData.postValue(DashboardRepository.getIncomeGraphData())
              loadingStateLiveData.postValue(false)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-creating a Job does not look like the best choice. You may launch new coroutine with `launch{..}` or `async{..}` functions and handle exceptions with ordinary `try/catch` blocks. If that is not enough - a `supervisorScope{..}` can help to make sure a parent Job is not terminated.

You may take a look at the docs for more details
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html